# Trying to find a Sensu plugin AWS S3

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, sensu

I'm trying to find or create a Sensu plugin to count AWS S3 objects within a folder. For example,

All buckets/test1/test2/

I want to know how many objects are within test2 and alert me if the number goes above the threshold.

I found this, but I'n not able to get it to work.

```
# by default you only get 1000 objects at a time
# so you have to roll your own cursor

S3.connect!

objects = []
last_key = nil
begin
  new_objects = AWS::S3::Bucket.objects(bucket_name, :marker => last_key)
  objects    += new_objects
  last_key    = objects.last.key
end while new_objects.size > 0

# you can easily define the above as an all_objects method on   AWS::S3::Bucket
```

If anyone knows a different way to do this, please let me know.

Thank you

Devon

Comment: What errors are you seeing? Have you configured your credentials?

Comment: @thun I have configured my credentials, I have other AWS rb scripts that work. I try to run this script, it seems to error out. Granted, I do not know the syntax of this script and I'm new to ruby. The other scripts had good comment examples.                                                                                        I run the script ./all_s3_objects.rb and get:                        ./all_s3_objects.rb: line 4: S3.connect!: command not found
./all_s3_objects.rb: line 6: objects: command not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to go a different route, I used this code to accomplish what I wanted to do.

```
#!/bin/bash
value=$(aws s3 ls bucket/dir1/dir2/ -- recursive --human-readable --summarize | grep .file type | wc -l)
if [ $value -gt 1000 ];
then
      echo "$value Warning"
      exit 2
fi
```

Thank you Everyone for the help

Devon